# Перевод времени в секунды в php

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, конвертация, типизация

Каким образом можно перевести время (продолжительность звонков) в секунды в php (не в sql) (тип $row["duration"] имеет тип в базе TIME)

```html
    $result = mysqli_query( $conn, "SELECT * FROM `calls`" );
    if($result) {
        $phptable=""; 
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                        $duration = TIME_TO_SEC($row["duration"]);
                        echo $duration;
        }
    }
```

В результате ругается на функцию `TIME_TO_SEC`.

**Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function TIME_TO_SEC() in C:\OSPanel\domains\calllog.ru\calllog.php:105 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\OSPanel\domains\calllog.ru\calllog.php on line 105**

Пытался искать - [перевод в минуты в php](https://www.google.ru/search?q=%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%20%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%20TIME%20%D0%B2%20%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8B%20%D0%B2%20php&ei=qWlVYfeWG-KwrgTWsK24DQ&oq=%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%20%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%20TIME%20%D0%B2%20%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8B%20%D0%B2%20php&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAM6BwgAEEcQsAM6BQgAEM0CSgUIOhIBMUoFCDwSATZKBAhBGABQqocHWPbhB2C17QdoB3ACeACAAZMFiAHME5IBCDguMTAuNS0xmAEAoAEByAEIwAEB&sclient=gws-wiz&ved=0ahUKEwi3j5fcmKbzAhVimIsKHVZYC9cQ4dUDCA4&uact=5), [документация](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/ref.datetime.php), но не нашел (везде конвертируется текущее время, а не продолжительность). Прошу не минусуйте меня - я новичок (я привел действия, которые делал - привел ссылки), отнеситесь с пониманием. Без вас я не решу эту проблему.

Comment: TIME_TO_SEC() - это функция mysql, а вы её пытаетесь вызывать в РНР

Comment: @Ипатьев я знаю, что это функция mysql. вопрос в том, как перевести время (прочтенное из базы данных) в секунды в php. Надо перевести в секунды $row["duration"]  в php.

Comment: в запросе. переводить  надо в запросе